# reading rss feed in wp7 with c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

How to read rss feed from here in wp7 app using c#: "http://www.nyc.gov/apps/311/311Today.rss"?

My Xaml code:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="titleTxt" Height="30" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="dateTxt" Height="30" Text="{Binding Date}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="descTxt" Height="30" Text="{Binding Desc}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My C# code:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("http://www.nyc.gov/apps/311/311Today.rss");
        XNamespace content = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
        var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
               .Select(i => new
               {
                   Title = i.Element("title").Value,
                   Date = DateTime.Parse(i.Element("pubDate").Value),
                   Desc = i.Element(content + "encoded").Value,
               })
                .ToArray();
        listBox1.ItemsSource = items;

    }
```

Comment: So [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have tried out sample codes from msdn but nothing is coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(wc.DownloadString("http://www.nyc.gov/apps/311/311Today.rss"));
    XNamespace content = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
    var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
            .Select(i => new
            {
                Title = i.Element("title").Value,
                Date = DateTime.Parse(i.Element("pubDate").Value),
                Desc = i.Element(content + "encoded").Value,
            })
            .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Cannot open 'http://www.nyc.gov/apps/311/311Today.rss'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I think you have some problems with your url. See your url and compare it the one in the answer. Above example works.

Comment: I have edited my code above. Please check if I have missed out something.

Comment: See the edit. I just followed the steps in the error message `The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14305/discussion-between-sana-and-l-b)

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote an entire tutorial covering this topic. Details here:

- [Building a RSS reader for Windows Phone 7 – Designing the structure](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows)
- [Building a RSS reader for Windows Phone 7 – Developing the functionality](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows-0)